# Good online resources to learn x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I came across many online resources about x86 assembly. However, before starting, I want to get some feedback from others. Is there any video resources especially focused to x86 assembly programming? I know C and have fundamentals in Java. I also know MIPS architecture and done assembly for MIPS. I need to know x86 assembly (especially protected mode) for job. I would appreciate if anyone can refer me to any good sites. There are some online sites that seemed useful to me-

http://www.vtc.com/products/Assembly-Language-Programming-Tutorials.htm

Would you please comment on that? Will it be useful if I follow those lectures?

I also downloaded **intel manuals**  but some people told me that it's too tough for the beginner.

Another site is: http://www.mindshare.com/shop/?c=e&section=0BA207001710

It covered the basic x86 architecture. Please help me to start with a good resource!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good x86 assembly book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845/good-x86-assembly-book)

Comment: "I also downloaded intel manuals but some people told me that it's too tough for the beginner." Did you try reading them yourself? Were they too tough?

Comment: Here is a repo with a bunch of runnable examples with asserts: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat

Answer (score 12):

You can't beat Jonathan Bartlett's Most Excellent "Programming from the Ground Up":

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/

Answer (score 4):

Ok so flame me, but I say Intel & AMD Manuals.  And examples other people assembly code. That's probably not what you are looking for, but still it might be the most important resource.  You saying *"especially protected mode"* make it sound like you might be playing with weird arcana that usually only for kernel hackers.  If so, then you really need to go to he horses mouth.

I think my point is that if you already know C and assembly in another architecture, you don't need a nice conceptual tutorial.  You do need the details.  You can find out the names of instructions by reading other peoples code, and then you read the manuals to find out what they really do.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have good knowledge in computer architecture and also know MIPS architecture and done some MIPS assembly coding. This is my current situation. However, I didn't work with low level C. Do you think that I am in the right track to grasp x86 assembly programming from intel manual?

Comment: Just try it and see.  I think writing simple ASM programs is usually easy and fun.  I managed to do that sort of thing by looking at other peoples code, rather than a book -- and the PDF that paulsm4 links to can't hurt.  I think you will need the manuals only when the going gets tough and you need to do some black magic.  The manuals are not easy to read, but sometimes there is little choice.